# How to access values within object within array within object within array using jQuery $.each?

Tags: jquery, nested, each

I'm trying to get at the values in objects that are within an array, that is the value of an object in an array.

**jQuery**

```
// aim:  to alert value of 'm1' for each object (represented as a day)

myArray = [{"monday":[{"m1":"val1"},{"s1":"val2"},{"m2":"val3"},{"s2":"val4"},{"m3":"val5"},{"s3":"val6"}]},{"tuesday":[{"m1":"val1"},{"s1":"val2"},{"m2":"val3"},{"s2":"val4"},{"m3":"val5"},{"s3":"val6"}]},{"wednesday":[{"m1":"val1"},{"s1":"val2"},{"m2":"val3"},{"s2":"val4"},{"m3":"val5"},{"s3":"val6"}]},{"thursday":[{"m1":"val1"},{"s1":"val2"},{"m2":"val3"},{"s2":"val4"},{"m3":"val5"},{"s3":"val6"}]},{"friday":[{"m1":"val1"},{"s1":"val2"},{"m2":"val3"},{"s2":"val4"},{"m3":"val5"},{"s3":"val6"}]},{"saturday":[{"m1":"val1"},{"s1":"val2"},{"m2":"val3"},{"s2":"val4"},{"m3":"val5"},{"s3":"val6"}]},{"sunday":[{"m1":"val1"},{"s1":"val2"},{"m2":"val3"},{"s2":"val4"},{"m3":"val5"},{"s3":"val6"}]}]

$.each(myArray, function(k,v) {
  $.each(k, function(k2,v2) {
      alert(v2.m1)
});
});
```

**jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/py8Jz/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/merrifield69/py8Jz/5/

```
$.each(myArray, function (k, v) {
    $.each(v, function (k2, v2) {
        alert(v2[0].m1)
    });
});
```

If you just take a second to think about where you are in each loop it's pretty easy to figure out. :]